# Injection of sub-component in Web Component

Tags: dependency-injection, web-component

Suppose I am creating the component which template contains special sub-components. For example:

```
<x-audio-player playlist-json="my_js_list"></x-audio-player>
```

with Shadow DOM

```
<x-playlist>
    <x-track name="Track 1"></xtrack>
    <x-track name="Track 2"></xtrack>
    <x-track name="Track 3"></xtrack>
</x-playlist>
```

Probably, somebody will have a need to completly change the view of tracks. So I need to give the possibility to change the Shadow DOM into:

```
<x-playlist>
    <y-track name="Track 1"></y-track>
    <y-track name="Track 2"></y-track>
    <y-track name="Track 3"></y-track>
</x-playlist>
```

So. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You are able to define multiple possible selections for your insertion points.
So you probably wanna do something like:

```
<template>
  <content select="x-track, y-track"></content>
</template>
```

Hope this helps!